# Connecting asterdata on cloudera

Tags: cloudera, sqoop

I am facing a problem connecting to aster data nCluster on `Cloudera`?

Is it possible using `sqoop`?

Comment: What does the API look like for both products?

Comment: Let me explain more my problem. I know that we can connect to the asterdata DB (which is nCluster) using Hortonworks connectors (I think it's sqoop). My question is can we use the same connector with a Cloudera infrastructure? Could the sqoop connector of Cloudera support the connection with nCloud? Thanks a lot!